# Strip tag but preserve it's content

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How do I strip tag `name` (if exists) preserving all of it's contents using XSLT 1.0?

input.xml:

```
<authors>
    <author>
        Author 1
    </author>
    <author>
        <sup>*</sup>Author 2
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>Author 3</name><sup>1</sup>
    </author>
    <author>
        <sup>**</sup><name>Author 4</name><sup>2</sup>
    </author>
</authors>
```

desired_output.xml:

```
<authors>
    <author>
        Author 1
    </author>
    <author>
        <sup>*</sup>Author 2
    </author>
    <author>
        Author 3<sup>1</sup>
    </author>
    <author>
        <sup>**</sup>Author 4<sup>2</sup>
    </author>
</authors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use only to skip only element name:**

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Below is complete XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just needed some time to figure out how it works.